# Decorators with arguments

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Code as follows

```
def my_dec(func):
    def wrap(w):
        t = func(w)
        return t * 4
    return wrap


@my_dec
def testing(n):
    return n


new = testing(3)
print(new)  # This prints 12
```

This example is working fine, but now I'm trying to add the following to the decorator `@my_dec(100)`, I need to multiply the given number by 100.

When I try this

```
@my_dec(100)
def testing(n):
    return n
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./deco2", line 10, in <module>
    @my_dec(100)
  File "./deco2", line 5, in wrap
    t = func(w)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How can I pass the `100` to the decorator?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first example, you correctly define the decorator as a function which takes the wrapped function, and returns a new function.

To add arguments, you need to write a function which takes the arguments, and *returns the decorator*, i.e. returns the function which takes the wrapped function and returns a function.

One way to do it:

```
def my_dec(x):
    def dec(func):
        def wrap(w):
            t = func(w)
            return t * x
        return wrap
    return dec
```

This might be slightly clearer if you think about what the `@` syntax expands to:

```
@my_dec(100)
def testing(n):
    return n
```

expands to:

```
def testing(n):
    return n
testing = my_dec(100)(testing)
```

Also, to reduce the high nesting level and make your decorator more readable and maintainable, you can define a decorator class instead, which takes its arguments in its `__init__`, and calls the wrapped function in its `__call__`.  There are plenty of examples online. You can start by reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666216/2096752).

There are also ways to make your decorator take optional arguments (i.e. so that both your examples work).

---

And if you really want to understand decorators in depth, read [Graham Dumpleton's blog](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/wrapt/tree/master/blog).  Highly recommended.