# Using classes as method decorators

Tags: python, class, decorator, python-decorators

While there are [plenty of resources about using classes as decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666216/decorator-classes-in-python), I haven't been able to find any that deal with the problem of decorating *methods*. The goal of this question is to fix that. I will post my own solution, but of course everyone else is invited to post theirs as well.

---

## Why the "standard" implementation doesn't work

The problem with the standard decorator class implementation is that python will not create a bound method of the decorated function:

```
class Deco:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func= func
    
    def __call__(self, *args):
        self.func(*args)

class Class:
    @Deco
    def hello(self):
        print('hello world')

Class().hello() # throws TypeError: hello() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

A method decorator needs to overcome this hurdle.

---

## Requirements

Taking the classes from the previous example, the following things are expected to work:

```
>>> i= Class()
>>> i.hello()
hello world
>>> i.hello
<__main__.Deco object at 0x7f4ae8b518d0>
>>> Class.hello is Class().hello
False
>>> Class().hello is Class().hello
False
>>> i.hello is i.hello
True
```

Ideally, the function's `__doc__` and signature and similar attributes are preserved as well.

Comment: Also relevant: [Python decorator best practice, using a class vs a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294014/python-decorator-best-practice-using-a-class-vs-a-function)

Comment: Why do you require it to be a class? What's wrong with the decorator just being a function?

Comment: @PaulRooney In my particular case (I'm writing a GUI library), I want to store a bunch of attributes on the function (like keyboard hotkey, description, category, etc.) and also a bunch of functions (like `.start_in_new_thread()`, `.update_status()`). Instead of forcing all these attributes onto the function, I'd rather write a wrapper class and replace the function altogether.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually when a method is accessed as `some_instance.some_method()`, python's [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) kicks in and calls `some_method.__get__()`, which returns a bound method. However, because the method has been replaced with an instance of the `Deco` class, that does not happen - because `Deco` is not a descriptor. In order to make `Deco` work as expected, it must implement a `__get__` method that returns a bound copy of itself.

### Implementation

Here's basic "do nothing" decorator class:

```
import inspect
import functools
from copy import copy


class Deco(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.__self__ = None # "__self__" is also used by bound methods

        self.__wrapped__ = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if bound to an object, pass it as the first argument
        if self.__self__ is not None:
            args = (self.__self__,) + args

        #== change the following line to make the decorator do something ==
        return self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # create a bound copy
        bound = copy(self)
        bound.__self__ = instance

        # update __doc__ and similar attributes
        functools.update_wrapper(bound, self.__wrapped__)

        # add the bound instance to the object's dict so that
        # __get__ won't be called a 2nd time
        setattr(instance, self.__wrapped__.__name__, bound)

        return bound
```

To make the decorator do something, add your code in the `__call__` method.

---

Here's one that takes parameters:

```
class DecoWithArgs(object):
    #== change the constructor's parameters to fit your needs ==
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

        self.__wrapped__ = None
        self.__self__ = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.__wrapped__ is None:
            return self.__wrap(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.__call_wrapped_function(*args, **kwargs)

    def __wrap(self, func):
        # update __doc__ and similar attributes
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

        return self

    def __call_wrapped_function(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # if bound to an object, pass it as the first argument
        if self.__self__ is not None:
            args = (self.__self__,) + args

        #== change the following line to make the decorator do something ==
        return self.__wrapped__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self

        # create a bound copy of this object
        bound = copy(self)
        bound.__self__ = instance
        bound.__wrap(self.__wrapped__)

        # add the bound decorator to the object's dict so that
        # __get__ won't be called a 2nd time
        setattr(instance, self.__wrapped__.__name__, bound)
        return bound
```

An implementation like this lets us use the decorator on methods as well as functions, so I think it should be considered good practice.